# Can't import maven project on mac

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project which can be successfully imported on my windows machine. However with the same settings.xml and pom.xml, I can't import it on my MAC. The `Unable to import maven project. See logs for details` erroe keeps showing up. The project relies on some private repository and the addresses is configured in settings.xml (since windows machine do the job successfully). Here is some of the log I get when importing:

```
2020-04-11 10:00:34,028 [ 407319]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: language for id: preferences.language.Kotlin.scripting 
2020-04-11 10:00:34,683 [ 407974]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 2020/4/11, 9:54) 
2020-04-11 10:02:21,424 [ 514715]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.customizeForResolve(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.resolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1261)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$1.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:482)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (Write failed)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:254)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.customize(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:167)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$400(RemoteUtil.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.lambda$invoke$0(RemoteUtil.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:45)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:219)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:151)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.customize(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.doCustomize(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.lambda$customizeForResolve$1(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (Write failed)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1829)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:722)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.releaseOutputStream(StreamRemoteCall.java:120)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:238)
    ... 31 more
2020-04-11 10:02:21,427 [ 514718]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4  Build #IU-193.6911.18 
2020-04-11 10:02:21,427 [ 514718]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 11.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-04-11 10:02:21,427 [ 514718]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Mac OS X 
2020-04-11 10:02:21,427 [ 514718]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.ReimportProject 
2020-04-11 10:02:27,780 [ 521071]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.customizeForResolve(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.resolve(MavenProjectsTree.java:1261)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorResolvingTask.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$1.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:482)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (Write failed)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:254)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.customize(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:167)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$400(RemoteUtil.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.lambda$invoke$0(RemoteUtil.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:45)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:219)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:151)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.customize(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.doCustomize(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenEmbedderWrapper.lambda$customizeForResolve$1(MavenEmbedderWrapper.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (Write failed)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1829)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:722)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.releaseOutputStream(StreamRemoteCall.java:120)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:238)
    ... 31 more
2020-04-11 10:02:27,781 [ 521072]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4  Build #IU-193.6911.18 
2020-04-11 10:02:27,781 [ 521072]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 11.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-04-11 10:02:27,781 [ 521072]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Mac OS X 
2020-04-11 10:02:27,781 [ 521072]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.ReimportProject 
2020-04-11 10:02:29,890 [ 523181]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=dmp, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=/Users/11113523/Code/dmp) RunManager took 24 ms
```

I think the main problem is `Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (Write failed)`. But I can't figure out what permission is denied from where. Could someone tell me how to make it right?

Comment: Do you have antivirus/firewall or other s/f that may block IDE connections? IDE needs working connection to loopback interface (`localhost`) for IPC communications. Check also that the user who runs the IDE has r/w permissions to [IDE config/caches](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) directories.

Comment: I closed the mac system firewall and give IDEA full disk access rights. Change the permission of the directory you mentioned to read and write for all users. The error still comes out.

Comment: Some software or OS policies blocks the IDE Maven import java process. You should look into this environment issue. Try complete IDE re-install. Review the OS policies. try to comment out the `::1             localhost` in `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the logs third line "#org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect". ¿Are you using intellij maven tool? Try to do it by command line. Execute inside your project folder:

```
mvn clean install
```

If it works, means that your IntelliJ is not pointing to your local maven settings file. To fix it, open your maven window in the IDE:

[intelliJ maven tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSIgR.png)

Next, make sure that your "user settings file" is pointing to correct file. How you can see in the image, by default the IDE not works with your local installation of maven, it has a bundled maven. You can use the bundled maven but pointing to your specific settings.xml:

[intelliJ maven options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkR2c.png)

I hope to be helpful.

Comment: Hi, `mvn clean install` from command line runs successfully. And i'm sure the maven home directory and settings.xml is pointed to the right position.

Comment: I think it's correct. With `127.0.0.1    localhost`, `255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
` and `::1    localhost `.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to run below command using terminal :

mvn clean install -U -DskipTests=true